# pandas groupby concatenate string in multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this pandas Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Team": ["Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees"],
        "Pos": ["Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher"],
        "Age": [24, 28, 40, 22, 29, 33, 31, 26, 21, 36, 25, 31]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

which looks like:

```
       Team          Pos  Age
0   Red Sox      Pitcher   24
1   Red Sox      Pitcher   28
2   Red Sox      Pitcher   40
3   Red Sox  Not Pitcher   22
4   Red Sox  Not Pitcher   29
5   Red Sox  Not Pitcher   33
6   Yankees      Pitcher   31
7   Yankees      Pitcher   26
8   Yankees      Pitcher   21
9   Yankees  Not Pitcher   36
10  Yankees  Not Pitcher   25
11  Yankees  Not Pitcher   31
```

What i'd like to do is to groupby Team and return the other columns as a concatenation the strings.

The outcome would look like

```
     Team          Pos  Age
0   Red Sox      Pitcher_24
1   Red Sox      Pitcher_28
2   Red Sox      Pitcher_40
3   Red Sox  Not Pitcher_22
4   Red Sox  Not Pitcher_29
5   Red Sox  Not Pitcher_33
6   Yankees      Pitcher_31
7   Yankees      Pitcher_26
8   Yankees      Pitcher_21
9   Yankees  Not Pitcher_36
10  Yankees  Not Pitcher_25
11  Yankees  Not Pitcher_31
```

Comment: I don't understand where the "groupby" concept is used in your example, nor why the desired output has only three rows corresponding to the first three rows of the input.  Where does the rest of the input go?

Comment: do you just need `df['Pos'] + '_' + df['Age'].astype(str)`?